# Why do people assume that if they don't understand a subject, it must be subjective?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This probably isn't a new or different complaint. In fact, I'm probably just blowing off steam because a perfectly [legitimate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806783/why-are-some-compiled-languages-slower-than-others) about facts, to which factual answers were and are entirely possible, got closed as "subjective.

> #### Why are some compiled languages slower than others?
>
> This may sound like a silly question, but I wonder because, to me, it seems that a programming language is merely a notation of operations. Broadly speaking, it all seems to come down to the compiler in the end. I can hardly imagine that a language is designed in such a way that the compiler cannot optimise code written in it in the same, or at least similar way that would be possible in other languages. Is this the case, however, or is there another reason behind it?

The fact remains: the people who voted to close this as subjective clearly don't understand the subject matter. I'd almost bet not a single one of them has written a single compiler (or even code generator for a compiler) in their life. Even without that experience, however, anybody who writes code at all should have a clue about the fact that the result of a program (the code generated by a compiler, in this case) is a result of the code that was written, and what it has to do.

I suppose you can argue that the code people write as parts of compilers can be influenced by their opinions (just like any other code is), but if we use that as a basis then SO might as well be shut down immediately, because *every* question is entirely subjective. Clearly that's not a reasonable basis for deciding what answers really qualify as "too subjective".

Edit: the difference between SO and M.SO is interesting. On SO it's closed because people read the question but didn't really understand the subject matter. Here on Meta, people proclaim that it's too broad because they apparently don't even understand English, or just didn't read the question itself, so they read "does X exist" as being too broad because it's impossible to list every possible X.

Comment: The correct close reason for that question is too broad, at the very least it's the far more appropriate and understandable reason.  I can see a justification for subjective, but you kinda have to work harder to get there.  It's pretty unambiguously and obviously too broad.

Comment: "speed" of a program is not a quantifiable as you seem to think it is.  There are a number of factors which affect speed, ranging from the processor speed to the type of hard drive, and those factors will change when you run the program on a different machine

Comment: @SamIam: are you honestly questioning whether it's possible to time how long it takes for code to execute? Of course the time varies with the hardware, but that's of precisely zero relevance to the question.

Comment: @Servy: yes and no. Of course it's not possible to list *every* design decision that a language could possibly make, and how that relates to the speed of compiled code. But also yes, it's entirely possible to give some reasonable examples of design decisions and how those decisions influence the speed of generated code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin So it's possible to provide an incomplete post that doesn't actually fully answer the question, but it can provide just a tip of the iceberg that is the answer.  That's a telltale sign that the question is too broad.  A complete answer cannot be given.  This question is so broad that even entire books or full college courses on the subject couldn't cover it completely.  The question needs to be way, way, way more specific for it to be answerable.

Comment: @Servy: Okay, so shut down SO immediately, because if you want a truly complete answer, the same is true of *every* question on SO.

Comment: @SamIam: Yes, zero relevance to the question (at least to the question of whether the original question should be closed). The original question is about language design. Yes, a good answer will probably at least mention the degree to which a language specifies properties that are more or less difficult to translate to specific assembly languages.

Comment: @Clive: Read the comments. Those claiming it's too broad are attempting to read "does X exist?" as meaning that a complete answer must list every possible value of X. It's pretty obvious their understanding of the simple English in the question if *badly* flawed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, some high-rep users here seem to complain about the flow of bad questions and the fact it seems difficult to find anything they consider sufficiently interesting to answer (I must say I've had this feeling too). Perhaps once you've answered enough narrow questions, you're just finding it more interesting to answer questions that are a bit broader in scope (like this one), which could lead to a good answer with a few paragraphs. Perhaps it's not the newbie questions that drive high-rep users away, rather it could be the fact that answerers "outgrow" the constraints of SO.

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe that it's *really* opinion based, but the question in its current form is much too broad.

There are hundreds of different optimisations in general and dozens of different languages to talk about, which makes this ridiculously difficult to address in a single answer.

If the question instead asked about a specific optimisation and why a language could not take advantage of this optimisation, that would be more appropriate.

Even within the tagged languages [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), there are different assumptions that can be made about what a particular piece of code can do (all of these languages have different levels of "safety") in each of these different languages, which could take up at least a few pages to talk about.

For the benefit of <10k, here's the question (which has now been deleted):

> ### Why are some compiled languages slower than others?
>
> This may sound like a silly question, but I wonder because, to me, it
>   seems that a programming language is merely a notation of operations.
>   Broadly speaking, it all seems to come down to the compiler in the
>   end. I can hardly imagine that a language is designed in such a way
>   that the compiler cannot optimise code written in it in the same, or
>   at least similar way that would be possible in other languages. Is
>   this the case, however, or is there another reason behind it?
>
> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler)

Comment: Now that i see the question (since I am <10k) it sounds like a valid question.  And in fact your answer to this meta sounds like a start of a valid answer.

Though I would like the question to specify what part is slow... is it "compiling" slowly or "running" slowly.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: the OP says "optimise code" in the question, so I'd presume it's the performance of the running code rather than the time taken to compile it. The main goal of a compile is to improve running performance anyway.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano if the answer can only start with "there's a thousand different optimizations and talking about all of here them is ridiculous", then the question is useless. Also, the fact that it's tagged java, c# and c++ makes it even worse as the user doesn't seem to know that java introduces an additional level of indirection over c++ due to being compiled to bytecode and then executed in a vm. You would also have to explain all differences due to the separate programming paradigms of the languages, and so on. Thus it's just entirely too broad.

Comment: @l4mpi: Consider the irony of your fitting a reasonable description of one of the major factors into a comment, but still claiming that it can't fit into an answer.

Comment: @JerryCoffin But it's still not a complete answer to the question.  It's just the very start of a lengthy explanation of just one of *many thousands* of things to talk about.  When a question is too broad it's *super easy* to *start* talking about just one tiny little piece of the puzzle.  A broad question isn't a question in which nobody can provide any useful information at all. That's an unclear question.  The problem with a question that's too broad is that no matter how much information you provide, it will never be enough.

Comment: The java C# and C++ tags are probably useless as it adds unneeded specificity to the question.  I just just compiler and optimization tags are enough.  However, couldn't the answer to this have some more common optimizations be brought up? I am not claiming to be a compiler expert, but I would guess something along the lines of knowing how the processing pipelines of a CPU so they can move code around to make it go faster would be part of it.

Comment: It may need something along the lines of stating whether it is "managed" code or not.  Though because of the Java and C# tags I would assume it is "managed" code so it's not really the compiler, but the VM it is running on.  Though in that case optimizations do not make sense as much because there's a separate compilation phase at runtime.

Comment: @Servy: Except that in this case it clearly *is* enough. Reread the question. The basic question is *not* asking about every possible language design decision that could influence speed of generated code. It's asking about whether such things exist or not. A good answer requires only **one** good example of such a thing, not an exhaustive list (though a few examples would undoubtedly be better than only one).

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's basically interpreting it as a list question then, which is [still not an appropriate SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki).  Also just see the text of the close reason for "Too Broad", it applies *exactly* to this question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've _named_ one reason for this, I did not _explain_ it in the detail I would guess the OP of the question needs to thoroughly understand it. Also, as Servy says, this is just one piece of the puzzle; even restricting the question to two bytecode-languages would still be rather broad. And only naming a single example why this can happen doesn't seem useful. There's no definite, complete, factual answer IMO, thus -> too broad. And for the record, I did write a compiler in university and a number of interpreted DSLs for work and fun since then :)

Comment: @Servy: Those claiming that it's too broad are the ones trying to interpret it as a list question--"list all the reasons a compiler might produce faster code from one source language than another." The question is "Does X exist?", not "list all values of X." The former is answerable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin and the question "Does X exist" is utterly trivial and thus useless. Of course it exists, otherwise all languages would have the same speed. How is answering the question by saying "Java and C differ in speed due to thousands of factors, one of them being that java is compiled to bytecode and interpreted in a vm, which introduces a level of indirection" useful? Even disregarding the fact that everybody who spends 10 minutes reading about how java and C are compiled and executed should already know this?

Comment: @l4mpi: You seem to be missing yet another point. In his case, "X" is not "do differences exist?", but "are there reasons differences *must* exist?" In other words, are the differences that exist simply due to differences in how the compilers are written, or really traceable to differences in the languages themselves. Different C89 compilers (for example) also produce different code, but in this case the differences clearly are *not* traceable to the language since they all compile the same language.

Comment: @JerryCoffin wouldn't that answer be equally trivial? "No, there's no reason these differences _must_ exist as you could in theory write a compiler that results in the optimal machine code representation for the given program (and machine), which would of course be the same for equivalent programs regardless of the language they are written in. In practice, this doesn't happen because of the thousands of factors above." Still not an useful answer; probably still above OPs head. I can't think of any good answers, can you describe what you think would be a satisfactory answer to the question?

Comment: @l4mpi: On a completely theoretical level, you *could* be right that a sufficiently intelligent compiler could work past all differences in source language. In reality, we have factors like aliasing in C and C++ that make it much more difficult to produce as good of code with them as with Fortran (which only allows aliasing in a very controlled way, via `common` blocks). A good answer could describe what aliasing it, how it arises, and how it hurts code generation (all *fairly* easy to describe in sufficient detail to be understandable to relative beginners).

Comment: @JerryCoffin but then we're back at "There's thousand reasons, I'll choose a few important ones and describe them a bit". You can only cover a few specific details of that, and you don't even know if these details are important for OP and other future readers... For me it comes down to the fact that SO questions are expected to be about specific, practical, answerable problems. OP fails in all three: there's no actual specific, practical problem involved, and you can never hope to answer it to a point where the "problem" is fully solved and the question can be used as a complete reference.

Comment: @l4mpi: You were wrong the first N times you said this, and now you think N+1 is going to change that?

Comment: @JerryCoffin everybody including Shog9 agreed with me the first N times that the question is really broad (and rather bad in general). You think insisting for the N+1st time we should polish that turd changes that? Maybe our definition of "specific programming problem" differs as well. Anyways, if you think it would be useful to have a more specific "what's aliasing, how does it arise, impacts on code generation" question, I'm sure you could write a great self-answered Q/A pair. But assume that question existed before the one discussed here, you wouldn't have closed them as duplicates, right?

Comment: @l4mpi: Would I have voted to close this as a dupe if that Q/A already existed? Yes, of course.

Comment: @JerryCoffin to reiterate, you would have closed "Why are some compiled languages slower than others" as a duplicate of "What is aliasing"? Because I'm pretty sure everybody else using the site would not consider these questions dupes. But anyways, this discussion is fruitless - you asked for reasons why the question got closed, and you've got a ton of them: The community considers it overly broad, somewhat subjective (which is debatable IMO) and it's just a plainly bad question. If you can't accept that, feel free to self-answer the same thing in a cleaned-up version and see how it goes.

Comment: @l4mpi: What? Who said anything about the other answer *only* talking about aliasing? I'm sure glad I have your permission to post and answer a question though. Without that, I might have had to stop participating on [SO] completely!

Answer (score 5):

A true expert on compilers could probably write a series of *really* good essays about how certain language features affect the optimizability (is that a real word?) of a language; possible even expressed in language that a passing decent programmer without deep experience in compilers could follow. I'd *love* to read that series even though I'm unlikely to ever implement a compiler for a Turing complete language again (and the only one I've done was a crappy, recursive-descent, immediate-code-generation toy modeled on the [Crenshaw tutorial](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)).

But ...

- The current expression of the question is horrible. That should be correctable, but it does lead me to wonder if the OP even has the background to understand the answer.
- Really good answers to this questions are going to be **big**. Like I said: a series of essays or a short book. You might squeeze a decent one into the character limit for posts but it would certainly be a *very long* post by Stack Exchange standards.

I'm a little surprised at the close reason chosen, but not enormously because most merely decent programmers don't seem to know the subject in any depth but *do* seem to have strongly held opinions on the matter. Reading the [pure amount](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) of [verbiage spilled](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) on related topics is telling.

If someone wanted to fix the text I could get behind a movement to undelete and re-open, but my money is on lots of crappy answers, a few informed ones addressing some part of the problem or another and very few or none that really tackle the whole problem.

Comment: Yes, a really good answer would be a lot longer than the average answer on SO, and yes, the original question could certainly benefit from some editing. Unfortunately, no matter how well it's reworded, it appears to me that even if you wrote a great answer ahead of time, it'd be open to question whether you get the question open and paste an answer before it was closed again. The claimed intent of SO is to promote *great* answers, but now seems intent on closing any and all questions to which truly great answers are even possible.

Answer (score 4):

I mostly agree [with dmckee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265941/why-do-people-assume-that-if-they-dont-understand-a-subject-it-must-be-subject/265981#265981), but it doesn't appear that anyone here has directly answered the question you asked...

Something I've noticed in myself over the years is a tendency toward scanning new questions looking for common anti-patterns. New users tend to make the same mistakes again and again, and after a while you start to just expect them. At first glance, this question appears to fall into the same boat as countless previous questions of... mixed value:

- [Is Fortran easier to optimize than C for heavy calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146159/is-fortran-faster-than-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052578/why-is-c-sharp-faster-than-ruby
- [Why is Python faster than Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252568/why-is-python-faster-than-ruby)
- [Is Jython faster than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251054/is-jython-faster-than-python)
- [Why is go language so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704417/why-is-go-language-so-slow)
- [Why did java have the reputation of being slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163411/why-did-java-have-the-reputation-of-being-slow)
- [How much faster is C++ than C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138361/how-much-faster-is-c-than-c)
- [Why do people say that Ruby is slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529852/why-do-people-say-that-ruby-is-slow)

...you get the idea. Sometimes these sorts of questions get decent answers; sometimes, they're asked in good faith. Often, they get a lot of attention simply because they're the programmer equivalent of "the Raiders are better than the Broncos, amirite?"

So I strongly suspect that folks read the question you're referencing and thought, "great, another excuse for a language pissing contest - nope."

Not because it *couldn't* be answered well. Because it probably *wouldn't* be answered well.

In all honesty, if you or someone else wanted to write a really comprehensive answer to a question like that, it might do a lot of good just to have it out there, if nothing else as something to point to the next time one of these questions comes up rather than launching into a debate over language idioms.

Comment: So would you say that people are careless in closing these sorts of questions based on a "quick scan" of the question, or is it valid for a person to vote to close these sorts of questions based on what they've seen before?

Comment: Both of those statements are true, @Qantas. Hence the difference between the reason the question was closed (opinion-based) and the criticisms raised here on meta (too broad).